# Golang VS Code Snippet: Mimic "built-in" `variable.print!` snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Context: The [Golang VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=golang.Go) has built-in snippets/macros for creating a `fmt.PrintX` statement from a given variable:

[image: .print! before]
[image: .print! after]

Note how the variable name is filled in for me.

I frequently write methods, and the Golang extension's `meth` snippet, in my opinion, is slow, since there are 5 (!) tab stops:

[image: meth tabstops]

So far, I've written a snippet that mimics the `meth` snippet:

```json
"Struct Method": {
    "prefix": ".meth",
    "body": [
        "func ($1 $2) $3($4) $5 {",
        "\t$6",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "some description"
}
```

And I would like this snippet to mimic the `print!` macro/snippet, where it fills in the variable name; for the method snippet, instead of filling a variable, it would automatically fill in the method receiver (`$1` and `$2`) with the first letter of the struct name, and the full struct name in the second.

So, if I have the following struct:

```golang
type SomeStruct struct {}
```

and type:

```golang
SomeStruct.meth
```

then activate the snippet, it should output:

```golang
func (s SomeStruct) .(.) . {
    .
}
```

where each `.` is a tab stop.

**Is this sort of snippet possible? If so, how can I write it so it does this?**

Comment: use the extension **Hypersnips**, with a regex prefix you can capture the struct name

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to make a snippet in a keybinding that can parse the current line.  Put this into your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+w",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "\n\nfunc (${TM_CURRENT_LINE/\\s*type\\s*(.)(.*)\\s* struct\\s*{}/${1:/downcase} $1$2)/} $1($2) $3 {\n\t$4\n}"
  },
  // "when": "langId == golang"
}
```

The workflow is different than what you mentioned but is also easier - you don't have to type `SomeStruct.meth`.  Just trigger the keybinding **at the end** of the `type SomeStruct struct {}` line as in the demo.

If you want to be anywhere in the document and trigger a snippet completion, then the `HyperSnips` extension may be the way to go.

[image: golang struct snippet]